# Replace relative url from the href attribute to an absolute path

Tags: jquery

I want to replace link url like this **http://www.aaa.com**/html/html/a01.html

```
<td class="screenID"><a href="../html/html/a01.html">a01</a></td>
<td class="screenID"><a href="../html/html/a02.html">a02</a></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest thing that could possible work (You might want to use a RegExp match if this is too limited)

```
$(".screenId a").each(function(i,anchor){    
    anchor.href = anchor.href.replace(window.location.hostname,"www.aaa.com")})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.screenID a').each(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href',link.replace('../','http://www.aaa.com/'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".screenID").find("a").each(function(){
    var hrefReplace = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).attr("href",hrefReplace.replace("../","http://www.aaa.com/"));
});
```